# How can I use JNA to pass byte[][] to go

Tags: java, arrays, go, jna

This is **go** code

```golang
import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)
//export Print
func Print(keys, values [][]byte) {
  for len(keys) > 0 {
  err := txn.Set(keys[0], values[0])
  errMustBeNil(err)
  fmt.Printf("%s %s", string(keys[0]), string(values[0]))
  keys = keys[1:]
  values = values[1:]
 }
}
```

This is **libPrint.h**

```
/*
  static assertion to make sure the file is being used on architecture
  at least with matching size of GoInt.
*/
typedef char _check_for_64_bit_pointer_matching_GoInt[sizeof(void*)==64/8 ? 1:-1];

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef _GoString_ GoString;
#endif
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void Print(GoSlice keys, GoSlice values);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This is my **Java** code,I want to put byte[] into pointer one by one,`GoSlice` is represents the array[] in `go`,I don't know if this is correct

```java
public interface Test extends Library {
  Test TEST = (Test) Native.load("Print", Test.class);

  void Print(GoSlice key, GoSlice val);

  class GoSlice extends Structure {
    public Pointer[] data;
    public long len;
    public long cap;
  }
  static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] byte1 = "key1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] byte2 = "value1new".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    GoSlice keys = new GoSlice();
    keys.data = new Pointer[1];
    keys.data[0] = new Pointer(byte1.length + 1);
    keys.len = 1;
    keys.cap = 1;

    GoSlice values = new GoSlice();
    values.data = new Pointer[1];
    keys.data[0] = new Pointer(byte2.length + 1);
    values.len = 1;
    values.cap = 1;

    keys.data[0].write(0, byte1, 0, byte1.length);
    values.data[0].write(0, byte2, 0, byte2.length);

    Test.TEST.Print(keys, values);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly,I feel that byte[][] is not correctly converted to the type in go.

> This is the console log after running the Java program

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001a2775a34, pid=64329, tid=0x0000000000002903
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-macos-aarch64) (8.0_332-b09) (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.332-b09 mixed mode bsd-aarch64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x3a34]  _platform_memmove+0xf4
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/user/project/hs_err_pid64329.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://www.azul.com/support/
#
```

**This is my first change**

```java
public interface TxnClient extends Library {
  TxnClient TNX_CLIENT = (TxnClient) Native.load("Tikv", TxnClient.class);

  int TxnSave(GoSlice[] key, GoSlice[] val);

  class GoSlice extends Structure {
    public long cap;
    public Pointer data;
    public long len;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
      return Arrays.asList("cap", "data", "len");
    }
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] key1 = "key1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] value1 = "value1new".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] key2 = "key2".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] value2 = "value2new".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    GoSlice tmp = new GoSlice();
    GoSlice[] keys = (GoSlice[]) tmp.toArray(2);
    keys[0].data = new Memory(key1.length + 1);
    keys[0].len = keys[0].cap = key1.length;
    keys[0].data.write(0, key1, 0, key1.length);

    keys[1].data = new Memory(key2.length + 1);
    keys[1].len = keys[1].cap = key2.length;
    keys[1].data.write(0, key2, 0, key2.length);

    GoSlice[] values = (GoSlice[]) tmp.toArray(2);
    values[0].data = new Memory(value1.length + 1);
    values[0].len = values[0].cap = value1.length;
    values[0].data.write(0, value1, 0, value1.length);

    values[1].data = new Memory(value2.length + 1);
    values[1].len = values[1].cap = value2.length;
    values[1].data.write(0, value2, 0, value2.length);

    int i = TxnClient.TNX_CLIENT.TxnSave(keys, values);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

```
5431788016 5431788016panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x9 pc=0x1225b2b80]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main.TxnSave({0x9, 0x143c281f0, 0x14000182000?}, {0x9, 0x143c281f0, 0x121daf2c8?})
    /Users/user/project/print.go:52 +0x180
```

**second change**

```golang
//export TxnSave
func TxnSave(keys, values [][]byte) (res int) {
 // ignore
}
```

```java
public interface TxnClient extends Library {
  TxnClient TNX_CLIENT = (TxnClient) Native.load("Tikv", TxnClient.class);

  int TxnSave(GoSlice key, GoSlice val);

  class GoSlice extends Structure {
    public long cap;
    public Pointer data;
    public long len;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
      return Arrays.asList("cap", "data", "len");
    }
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] key1 = "key1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] value1 = "value1new".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] key2 = "key2".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] value2 = "value2new".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    GoSlice keys = new GoSlice();
    keys.data = new Memory(key1.length + key2.length + 1);
    keys.data.write(0, key1, 0, key1.length);
    keys.len = keys.cap = key1.length + key2.length;
    keys.data.write(key1.length, key2, 0, key2.length);

    GoSlice values = new GoSlice();
    values.data = new Memory(value1.length + value2.length + 1);
    values.len = values.cap = value1.length + value2.length;
    values.data.write(0, value1, 0, value1.length);
    values.data.write(value1.length, value2, 0, value2.length);

    int i = TxnClient.TNX_CLIENT.TxnSave(keys, values);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

```
[2022/07/31 22:36:57.225 +08:00] [INFO] [client.go:378] ["[pd] create pd client with endpoints"] [pd-address="[127.0.0.1:2379]"]
[2022/07/31 22:36:57.228 +08:00] [INFO] [base_client.go:350] ["[pd] switch leader"] [new-leader=http://127.0.0.1:2379] [old-leader=]
[2022/07/31 22:36:57.228 +08:00] [INFO] [base_client.go:105] ["[pd] init cluster id"] [cluster-id=7126545341327379321]
[2022/07/31 22:36:57.228 +08:00] [INFO] [client.go:673] ["[pd] tso dispatcher created"] [dc-location=global]

4981923696 4981923392panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x8 pc=0x12b00a6e0]
// this is error
goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main.TxnSave({0x8, 0x128f21f70, 0x14000190000?}, {0x12, 0x128f21e40, 0x12a806d38?})
    /Users/user/go-tikv/tikv.go:53 +0x180
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the `Pointer` constructor's argument.  It's a native peer value, not an allocation size.

What you have:

```java
keys.data[0] = new Pointer(byte1.length + 1);
```

From the `Pointer` [Javadoc](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.12.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#Pointer-long-):

> `public Pointer(long peer)`
>
> Create from native pointer. Don't use this unless you know what you're doing.

The correct way to allocate new memory (which calls `malloc()` internally) is the `Memory` class which extends `Pointer`.  The argument for the `Memory` constructor [is indeed the size](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.12.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html#Memory-long-):

> `public Memory(long size)`
>
> Allocate space in the native heap via a call to C's malloc.
>
> Parameters:
>
> size - number of *bytes* of space to allocate

So you want:

```java
keys.data[0] = new Memory(byte1.length + 1);
```

One other note:

`Memory` isn't cleared on allocation, so if you want that "+1" null terminator you need to either `clear()` the memory or explicitly set that null byte when writing a string to it (or perhaps append a null byte to the string in Java before converting to bytes).

Updating for your follow-on questions:

You have a mismatch between the C header (which has `data` first followed by `len` and `cap` and your own `GoSlice` structure definition which puts `data` in the middle.  When you pass this to native, you are just sending the value of that initial `long` which is probably zero, and getting the `nil` pointer error.

Additionally, you are not allocating enough memory for what you're doing.  When you declare a `Structure` in JNA it allocates the memory it needs.  In your earlier version of code you used `Structure.toArray()` to allocate more memory for more structures -- this was correct (but you did it twice!).  You should do that once.

In your latest code you set `value` as just one `GoSlice` structure. That memory is just 24 bytes, for the two `long`s and the `Pointer`.  But then for your second array value you are using the original `data` (which is in the wrong order) and trying to write to a memory location that isn't even allocated.

In summary:

1. Declare the field order in your Java `GoSlice` to match the native header
2. Use the Structure's `toArray()` on an initial GoSlice structure to allocate space for an array of them.
3. Use the `data` field of the GoSlice[n] structure to write the string values to.

Comment: Thanks you,but how can i convert java byte[][] to go [][]byte, The GoSlice i was writed cannot correctly work

Comment: I had changed my question,can you help me deal with it

Comment: A bit busy to answer now but I need more information on exactly what the 2D array is. Is it an array of pointers or a contiguous array delimited by nulls?

Comment: Why I need use Jna to pass byte[][] to go? Because,I need use `go tikvTxnClient`.i want to save more than one key-value into my tikv.one key is a byte[],one value is a byte[],but i need pass more than one key and value.so i need  put them into byte[][]

Comment: the byte[][] is a contiguous array delimited by nulls,i can forEach and get them on go

Comment: Thanks for you to answer my question :),i had changed method and params,i do not how to modify it.

Comment: Updated my answer to summarize what I have said in comments.

Comment: oh thank you,i maybe understand what you told.Thanks!! :)